# Importing generic JS functions into Angular module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Bit of an Angular/Typescript newb here.

I've set up a JavaScript library of exported, helper functions that I know want to import into an Angular components, and use in those components' .html template files.

Here's my Javascript library, template-functions/data-types.ts:

```
export const isNumeric = val => !Array.isArray(val) && (val - parseFloat(val) + 1) >= 0;
```

It's a simple arrow function that I'm exporting:

Here's how I'm importing it in my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel } from '../model/my-model';
import { isNumeric } from '../template-functions/data-types';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-module',
  templateUrl: './my-module.html'
})

export class MyModule implements OnInit {

  @Input() public mymodeldetails: MyModel;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  // isNumeric = val => !Array.isArray(val) && (val - parseFloat(val) + 1) >= 0;
}
```

This is after several hours of having the Angular compiler and VSCode telling me that it couldn't find the data-types module, even though the path was correct.  I had a .js file extensions instead of a .ts one!

So now Angular can see my isNumeric function, but I'm the .html template file does not see it with what I've done so far.  The browser throws the error "_co.isNumeric is not a function".

What more do I need to do to get my Angular template to see my imported function?

I'm using Angular 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it visible in the template, wrap it in a component method:

```
import { isNumeric } from '../template-functions/data-types';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  isNumeric(val: any): boolean {
    return isNumeric(val);
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqqlau) for a demo.

---

As explained in the Angular template syntax [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context):

> The expression context is typically the *component* instance. (...)
>   Template expressions cannot refer to anything in the global namespace
>   (except `undefined`). They can't refer to `window` or `document`. They can't
>   call `console.log` or `Math.max`. They are restricted to referencing
>   members of the expression context.

Comment: Note: in the code snippet above, I use `MyComponent` as the component class, just to make it clear for future readers that we are referring to a component. Using `MyModule` as the name of an Angular component class could be confusing.

Comment: I'm sure that I had it like this at one point, but I couldn't have done so because it didn't work then.  It works now though, so thank you very much.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

To use an imported function in the template, assign it to a property.

```
import { isNumeric } from '../template-functions/data-types';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    isNumeric = isNumeric;
}
```